# Is it possible to intercept every command entered into an interactive shell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to be able to wrap every command I manually enter into an interactive Powershell console with my own function, is there a way to intercept this in a sane way? What I'm trying to accomplish is to time every command, and if it takes more than say 30 seconds, automatically pop up a BurntToast notification when it finishes.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to measure execution time of interactive commands, but not alter or interrupt them, then you can override `Out-Default` command:

```
function Out-Default {
    begin {
        $StartTime = Get-Date
        $OutDefault = { Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Out-Default @args }.GetSteppablePipeline($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $OutDefault.Begin($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput, $ExecutionContext)
    }
    process {
        if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
            $OutDefault.Process($_)
        } else {
            $OutDefault.Process()
        }
    }
    end {
        $OutDefault.End()
        $OutDefault.Dispose()
        $ExecutionTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime
        if($ExecutionTime -gt (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30)) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -Object $ExecutionTime
            # popup toast notification
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object $ExecutionTime
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell implicitly inject `Out-Default` command, for it to display result in PowerShell console.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use jobs for something like that:

```
function Invoke-CommandWithTimeout {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [array]$ArgumentList = @(),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$Timeout = 30
    )

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ArgumentList
    Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout $Timeout
    if ($job.State -ne 'Stopped') {
        $job.StopJob()
        Write-Warning 'Command timed out.'
    }
    Receive-Job -Job $job
    Remove-Job -Job $job
}

Invoke-CommandWithTimeout {Test-Connection 'server.example.org'}
```

I'm not aware of a way to automatically and transparently intercept any command entered in a PowerShell console and run it in a different way.